# Google play console ask app developer 'Remember to implement account hold and restore in your app by November 1, 2020' What does that mean?

Tags: google-play-console

> You must have an account hold and restore implemented in your app by November 1, 2020. Subscription pause and resubscribe will also be enabled by default unless you explicitly opt out.

In my google play console shows this warning. I don't have any paid apps in my Google Play Console account yet. Can anyone tell me what is this issues?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: That really sucks, Mayken. This is the first result that shows up from Google and it's a very hot topic and now people won't be able to find the answer to it.

Comment: @Makyen please reconsider, it's not off-topic and it's related somehow to programming.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat Your comment implies you haven't read the links I provided. As this question is written, it's asking us to interpret Apple's requirements. Such questions are off-topic (see above links). If you, or someone else, wants to ask a question like "How do I implement account hold and restore for my Android app?", that probably isn't inherently off-topic. It's probably too broad and/or may be a duplicate. Two questions, separately asking how to implement "account hold", with the other asking how to implement "account restore" are more likely to not be too broad (i.e. not "need focus").

Comment: @Makyen no issues, from another point of view that may be off-topic

Answer (score 2):

Whether you have a paid app or in-app purchases or you use any external payment gateway you will not face any issues unless you have any subscription model from Google Play Billing.